# Groovy - multi capturing group

Tags: regex, groovy, string-matching

I want to extract from a string a couple of words whenever they are present.
I tried something but the result is not what I expect.

```
def myString = 'blablabla bla bla blabla New User: John_user function: auditor blablablablabl bla blab New User: Do_user function: auditor2 blablabl blablb...'
def m = myString =~ /\sNew User:\s(.+_user)\sfunction:\s(auditor|auditor2)\s/
```

I want to have something like:

```
println m[0][1] //John_user
println m[0][2] //auditor

println m[1][1] //Do_user
println m[1][2] //auditor2

....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `.+` with `[^_]`:

```
\sNew User:\s([^_]+_user)\sfunction:\s(auditor|auditor2)\s
              ^^^^^
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qJ4rE6/2)

The reason why your regex overfires is that `.+` grabs the whole string and then starts backtracking, looking for a valid match to return. It find the last occurrence of `_user`, and puts the whole `John_user function: auditor blablablablabl bla blab New User: Do_user` into the first capturing group - which we can avoid if we restrict the pattern to only search for all characters but an underscore (with `[^_]`).

You can achieve a similar result with `.+?`, but a negated character class is more efficient. However, if your user names can contain `_` symbols, you will have to use this construct and the regex will look like

```
\sNew User:\s(.+?_user)\sfunction:\s(auditor|auditor2)\s
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/qJ4rE6/3)

Comment: Just FYI: you may also want to add quantifiers to `\s` subpatterns so that you can either match 0 or more whitespaces (`\s*`) or 1 or more (`\s+`).

Comment: Thanks. Supposing I have a user name contains `_` how managing that?

Comment: Then, as I wrote at the end of the answer, replace `[^_]` with `.+?`. It will be less efficient, but should work with user names containing `_` symbols. I updated the answer to include this requirement.